# How do I interpret this Boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

Please help me to understand this Boolean expression:
$$1 < a_i < 10^6$$
My first guess is this: One less than a modulo i and also less than 10 to the 6th power. Is my interpretation correct?
For context, this is part of a constraint to a problem that I'm trying to solve at HackerRank: [image: Screenshot from problem screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_i$ is a positive integer. It is an entry of the array.

$a_i$ is the $i$-th entry of the array $a$. $i$ is the index here.

We are told that $a_i$ is an integer that is bigger than $1$ and less than $10^6$.

For example, it is possible that $a_2 = 100$ but we won't have $a_2 = 10^6+1$, we also won't have $a_3=1$.

Answer (score 0):

In this problem specification, the constraints of the form 
$$ a \leq b \leq c $$
mean $b \in [a,c] \cap \mathbb{Z}$.  That is, $b$ is an integer in the range $[a,c]$.

In this problem specification, $n$ is between $1$ and $10^5$, inclusive, $d$ is between $1$ and $n$, inclusive.  And the $n$ space separated integers on the second line of the input are $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$.  Each of these is between $1$ and $10^6$, inclusive.

Comment: I'm not a mathematician so your equation on the second line confuses me. I understand what your saying though except that Siong further explained the  subscript which helped me understand this further. Thanks for answering though.